# Attach objects to wall without camera tracking in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, 3d

I want to attach a video to a wall that appears in a main video, like this:

[image]

Problem is that video is static shot, is not a track movement. So, I watched videos that explain how to make Motion 3D Tracking, with the Camera track, but it does not work, and I think is due to my video is static. So, how can I put another video with perspective there? I mean, I want to use something similar to the PS Perspective Crop Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a static shot, you don't need any tracking at all.

Use the built-in Corner Pin tool to reposition the corners of the thing you want to stick on the wall:

[image]

If you want to make it look more convincing afterwards, you could:

- Add a tiny bit of movement to the whole comp,
- Add motion blur to your sign, add a subtle shadow to the pinned sign matching the direction of the light in the video,
- Make sure the colour correction and grain/noise on your sign match those of your background video

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called **planar tracking.** Instead of tracking points, planar tracking tracks whole clusters of pixels within a rectangle, or a plane (hence the name planar). Fortunately ,most After Effects versions come with a basic version of the most popular planar tracker, Boris FX Mocha. Just search "Mocha AE" in the Effects & Presets panel.